# Check box inside a gridview

Tags: c#-4.0

In my application , inside a grid view each and every row contains a check box. After clicking that check box i have to access the entire row data. But iam unable to find that row. Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code it may helps..

protected void RdbLstStudentType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        GridViewRow gridRow = ((sender as CheckBox).Parent).Parent as GridViewRow;
        int currentRowIndex = gridRow.RowIndex;
```

}

by using this currentrowindex, you can access the entire row .